# SymmetricDS stop repush the lost data when source node off

Tags: symmetricds

I have installed SymmetricDS for 1 week with noproblem but today, i turn off the source node to upgrade RAM and CPU. When turn on the Source node again.There are a lot of missing data.

Why was that ? and how can i restransfer the lost data ?
Thanks

I tried to restart the SymmetricDs but no success

Answer (score 0):

If source node can connect to all target nodes in case of pull channels or to wait for target nodes to connect to it in case of push channels, nothing else should be done. Just wait and observe `sym_outgoing_batch` and `sym_incoming_batch` at the source and target nodes.

Comment: Boris is correct that it should just pick up where it left off with synchronization if the node is turned off and turned back on.   If you did need to fully reload the target you can set the intial_load_enabled flag in the sym_node_security table for the target to have a full set of data resent.